# Flutter downloader error when donwload certain files

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, mobile

I´m making an anime/manga app using Flutter, also I'm using the FlutterDownloader plugin. The thing is that I don't have any problem downloading videos/images like this URL:

https://cm.blazefast.co/1b/bb/1bbb3ad2d5d8e759166145fd82cfdbf6.jpg

But this URL doesn't work (even if the status code is 200):

https://lc3-cdn.t34798ndc.com/r25ZyBe/Fx8e_AxtJ_XMJ/M/Mx-4iJj-Mx-jVJj-wVJ/tM.0pUT0/XE.U/6lZG.pTcSUWW/tM.pTcSUWm-fa1.U/TU-UcSTSTDWHU.Yyk.jpg

This is the code:

```
    var url2 = Uri.parse(url);
    // make http get request
    var response = await http.get(url2);
    Directory a = Directory(savePath);
    if (response.statusCode == 200 && await a.exists()) {
      try {
        await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
          url: url,
          savedDir: savePath,
          fileName: isManga ? "$number.png" : "$number.mp4",
          showNotification:
              true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
          openFileFromNotification:
              true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
        );
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }
```

Logs of the second URL that has the error:

```
W/System.err(11668): java.io.IOException: Operation not permitted
W/System.err(11668):    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
W/System.err(11668):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.createFileInAppSpecificDir(DownloadWorker.kt:503)
W/System.err(11668):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:392)
W/System.err(11668):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)
W/System.err(11668):    at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/DownloadWorker(11668): Create a file using java.io API failed
D/DownloadWorker(11668): Update too frequently!!!!, but it is the final update, we should sleep a second to ensure the update call can be processed
D/DownloadWorker(11668): Update notification: {notificationId: 26, title: 1.png, status: FAILED, progress: -1}
W/System.err(11668): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(11668):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.downloadFile(DownloadWorker.kt:393)
W/System.err(11668):    at vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker.doWork(DownloadWorker.kt:206)
W/System.err(11668):    at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
W/System.err(11668):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(11668): Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=8955aeb7-4eef-4281-947e-1e1575e711b8, tags={ flutter_download_task, vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadWorker } ]
```

I have all the permissions. With the first URL, it downloads great in the directory I choose. It only happens when its downloaded from other source than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i found the solution. It turns out that the problem wasn´t the URL, it was the path where it was downloaded. As it seems, the are some special characters forbidden in android such as:
":",
"/",
"",
"|".
So because of that, in some names, those characters had to be replaced with a simple dash.

```
finalPath = Directory('$pathDir/$title ($lang)/${'chapter'.tr} ${j + 1}'.replaceAll(":", "-").replaceAll("|", "-"));
```

So I´ll leave this response, in case someone else encounters the same problem as I did

Answer (score 0):

Check if the URL you're trying to download from needs to be URL-encoded. Use Uri.encodeFull(url) to encode the URL before making the HTTP request.

```
var url2 = Uri.encodeFull(url);
var response = await http.get(url2);
```

Comment: Still with the same error...